# Make Div a Link

Tags: jquery, css

I have two div's which I would like to be clickable. Each div has an anchor link within which I would like to use for each div's link.

I'm using the help below which works for the left div but not the right.
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-entire-div-clickable

Not quite sure what I'm missing or if there is a better way to do this? Ideally I would like to use just CSS but this option would still work even if js is disabled.

Any help would be great.

```
$('.left').click(function(){
     window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href");
     return false;
});
$('.right').click(function(){
     window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href");
     return false;
});


    <div class="left">
    <div class="left-content">
        <h2><a href="#">title</a></h2>

        <ul>
            <li>Link</li>
            <li>Link</li>
            <li>Link</li>
        </ul>
    </div>   
</div>

<div class="right">
    <div class="right-content">
        <h2><a href="#">title</a></h2>

        <ul>
            <li>Link</li>
            <li>Link</li>
            <li>Link</li>
        </ul>
    </div>        
</div>
```

Comment: I assume in the real version the hrefs on your `<a>`s are not just a #, right?

Comment: there is no way to do this without JS -- css can't add the click() event to the div, which is what you need in order for it to be clickable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting DIVs inside of anchors is valid in HTML5 and is backwards compatible with other DOCTYPES.

```
<a href="#">
    <div class="right">
        <div class="right-content">
            <h2>title</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>Link</li>
                <li>Link</li>
                <li>Link</li>
            </ul>
        </div>        
    </div> 
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks thats looks like a nice solution didn't know you could wrap anchors around div's. As long as it validates looks like the best option rather than js.

Answer (score 2):

Use it this way:

```
$('.left').click(function(){
     window.location=$(this).children("a:first").attr("href");
     return false;
});
$('.right').click(function(){
     window.location=$(this).children("a:first").attr("href");
     return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UPEzq/2/)

```
$(document).on('click','.clickable', function(){
    window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href");
    return false;

});
```

the only thing that I've added is pointer on hover.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS. Give your anchor tags `display: block;`. Then put `ul` inside the `a`.

Here is a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ckenney108/Ld49u/). If you hover over either `div`, you'll see that they are both clickable.