# How to click div, smooth scroll to anchor? via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div set up as a link. On click, it travels to an anchor within the page. Used this method to make an entire div a link: [Make Div a Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690071/make-div-a-link)

The problem is not the function of the link itself, but that I can't get it to smooth scroll to the anchor. Smooth scrolling *was* working prior to setting the div as the link (when it was just a text link).

Can't get the two scripts to play nicely.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
        }, 500);
        return false;
    });
    $("div#learnMore").click(function() {
        window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Set up a JSFiddle here with the full code: http://jsfiddle.net/HNbdm

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what you are looking for is a slight changed version of a "smooth scroll to top" button try searching that in google https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollIntoView

Comment: Is there a reason you're using both methods?

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/HNbdm/3/) works fine for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery scroll To Element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have `$($.attr(this, 'href'))`.

I'm also not sure why you're using both functions here. All you need is one:

```
$("#learnMore").click(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $("#more").offset().top
    });
});
```

When you click on the `#learnMore` `div`, it scrolls the page to the top of your `#more` `div` smoothly.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/HNbdm/3/)